# Collapsing toolbar isn't collapsing with Drawer Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

A beginner here. My collapsing toolbar is reacting as a regular toolbar, no collapsing  behavior.

This is the activity where I have drawer layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/includedLayout"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_activity_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_activity_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**In above layout , this layout is included which has all other content app_bar_activity_drawer.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity_drawer">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/content_activity_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**And here is the layout content_activity_drawer.xml that is included in above layout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/helloLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activity_drawer"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_activity_drawer">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What is the problem , please tell..
and thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not adding a collapsing toolbar in your layout,

[From the documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)

> To add a collapsing toolbar to your layout, place the
>   CollapsingToolbarLayout inside an AppBarLayout. Then, add a Toolbar
>   and any other views as a child to the CollapsingToolbarLayout. Make
>   sure that the entire view structure is inside a CoordinatorLayout to
>   take advantage of CollapsingToolbarLayout’s scrolling and features.

A layout with a collapsing toolbar might look something like this:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Scrollable view here -->

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/tall_toolbar_height">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

      <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

see the link for more details

Comment: I put my toolbar under collapsingToolBarLayout and it gave exception..

Process: com.example.canvastag, PID: 27282
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.canvastag/com.example.canvastag.activity_drawer}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.google.support.design.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.google.support.design.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout